# Circle radius in meters using mapbox-gl

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox-gl

I've html page with **mapbox-gl-js v2.14.1** inside, and successfully generate circle radius using this code.

```
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'point',
  'type': 'circle',
  'source': 'point',
  'paint': {
    'circle-radius': [
      'interpolate',
      ['linear'],
      ['zoom'],
      8, 5,
      18, 250
    ],
    'circle-color': $('header').css("background-color"),
    'circle-opacity': 0.5,
    'circle-stroke-color': $('header').css("background-color"),
    'circle-stroke-width': 1
  }
});
```

It works like a charm, the circle size respects zooming event. How to make the circle size radius within 500 meters?

I tried this code, but it doesn't work, there is no console log error. It only displays very small circle in map, and when zooming in, the circle size doesn't change.

```
map.addLayer({
  'id': 'point',
  'type': 'circle',
  'source': 'point',
  'paint': {
    'circle-radius': [
      'interpolate',
      ['exponential', 2],
      ['zoom'],
      0, 0,
      20, [
        '/',
        ['*', 500, 0.075],
        ['cos', ['*', ['get', 'lat'], ['/', Math.PI, 180]]],
      ],
    ],
    'circle-color': $('header').css("background-color"),
    'circle-opacity': 0.5,
    'circle-stroke-color': $('header').css("background-color"),
    'circle-stroke-width': 1
  }
});
```